# Does Java have an internal JSON library that doesn't require adding explicit jar reference?

Tags: java, json

Is there any internal library in Java for JSON processing? Basically this should not require adding jar reference explicitly. The reason is quite involved, but in short I can say that once I compile my code and build a jar around it, it is  going to be executed by some third party tool which has trouble in adding external jar references.So, I am trying to figure out if I can rather make use of internal JSON library, though lightweight, if available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no internal core JSON parsing capability in Java(JDK) and this makes good sense. The beauty of the java ecosystem is that libraries can be added easily if you want to expand functionality. If you want to deploy your .jar as a single executable file then compile all libraries into a single jar.

If you are using maven (and you should) see the following for how to 'compile to single executable jar' 
[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)